# Is there a pointer event that equals to 'click' event?

Tags: javascript, html, click, mouseevent, pointer-events

The 'click' event is a mouse event which fires after both the mousedown and mouseup events have fired.

Now pointer event has a broader use case, so I wonder if there is a corresponding 'click' event for pointer event also?

Thanks.
Andy

Comment: There's `pointer-down` event, and `pointer-up` event. You're looking for a `pointer-down-then-up` event?

Comment: Not entirely clear what you're asking.

Comment: No there isn't and you apparently already know what it takes to make one yourself: consecutive pointerdown + pointerup on the same target. As you said pointer events have broader use cases, they also are more "raw". click is a composed event, you have to compose it yourself from pointerevents

Comment: [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Pointer_events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Pointer_events)

Comment: I can't tell what OP is asking?

Comment: @terrymorse yes I was wondering if there is an existing 'pointer-down-then-up' event?

Comment: @Kaiido ok so it seems I need to make a composed event using pointerdown and pointerup. just want to make sure 'click' event won't be triggered for touch events right?

Comment: I have a little pointer events test page that displays all pointer events sent to a target on the page. [Test of Pointer Events](https://terrymorse.com/devtools/pointerevents/index.html). Try it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As to the question: Is there a pointer event that's equivalent to the `click` event?

The answer is no.

As to the question: Does a pointer press dispatch a `click` event?

Answering that may take some testing.

Using a little [test page that reports every pointer event and click event](https://terrymorse.com/devtools/pointerevents/index.html), I obtained the following events for a single finger press on an iPhone:

```sh
16:01:45.416 - pointerover - width: 48.5, height: 48.5
16:01:45.417 - pointerenter - width: 48.5, height: 48.5
16:01:45.418 - pointerdown - width: 48.5, height: 48.5
16:01:45.601 - pointerup - width: 0.0, height: 0.0
16:01:45.602 - pointerout - width: 0.0, height: 0.0
16:01:45.602 - pointerleave - width: 0.0, height: 0.0
16:01:45.636 - click - width: NaN, height: NaN
```

(the width and height values report the size of the pointer tip, which in this case is a finger)

So it seems that at least on an iPhone, a `click` event is dispatched with a finger press.

Comment: Btw I found this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Touch_events/Supporting_both_TouchEvent_and_MouseEvent. It says for many browsers the touch event will also fire a mouse event.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this should've been a comment, but...

On [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/click_event) they state that "click" event is a MouseEvent.

And surely in desktop firefox the snippet below logs a MouseEvent.

```js
document.querySelector("div").addEventListener("click", (ev) => {
 document.write(ev.constructor.name);
});
```

```html
<div>CLICK ME</div>
```

However, on desktop chrome, it logs "PointerEvent"!

To answer your question (in a hacky way):

If you only target chrome, you can check `ev.pointerType` to distiguish between "mouse" and "touch". This means "click" event is generic, it will tell you "what clicked" in its event details. At least on chrome.

**Edit:**
I just noticed that [spec](https://w3c.github.io/uievents/#event-type-click) allows for chrome's behavior.

> Interface    [PointerEvent](https://www.w3.org/TR/pointerevents3/#pointerevent-interface)